# Ansible MariaDB 10.1.47 no password is forced

Tags: mysql, ansible, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04

after running the following ansible script, root login on mysql server (root@localhost) pass login without password promp. (with cli commands have no problems)

```
- name: "Set the root password"
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: ''
    name: root
    password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    priv: "*.*:ALL,GRANT"
    check_implicit_admin: yes
    host: localhost
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


- name: "Remove all anonymous user accounts"
  mysql_user:
    name: ''
    host_all: yes
    state: absent
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


#mysql_secure_installation
- name: "Remove MySQL test database"
  mysql_db:
    name: test
    state: absent
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


- name: "Creates db"
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ db_name }}"
    state: present
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

For now I'm using this workaround and It's working correctly.

```
- name: "Set database password"
  command: mysql --user=root --password={{ mysql_root_password }} --execute="SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('{{ mysql_root_password }}')";

- name: "Grant all to root"
  command: mysql --user=root --password={{ mysql_root_password }} mysql --execute="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';";

- name: "Disable socket plugin"
  command: mysql --user=root --password={{ mysql_root_password }} mysql --execute="update user set Plugin='' where User='root';";

- name: "Flush privileges"
  command: mysql --user=root --password={{ mysql_root_password }} mysql --execute="flush privileges";
```

It looks it doesn't like unix_socket_plugin, but without, it doesn't connect even if I specify mysql-client password in .my.cnf

Comment: Installed Mariadb 10.4.17 from repositories and have no problem, all is working fine.

Comment: Just a suggestion the workaround is not a good idea especially if you are doing " name: "Flush privileges"" On production software, please dont....... Has too many security problems to list....

Comment: Ansible module `mysql_user` does a `flush privileges;` every times it applies a privilege, right?